# Cross Compiled jar file with scala version : Spark

Tags: apache-spark, scala-ide

I cant run my very first simple spark program with scala ide.

I checked all my properties and i believe that are correct.

this is the [link](http://prntscr.com/dge0s9) with the properties.

any help ?

Comment: In your case, Spark artifacts use Scala 2.10 and you are trying to include Scala 2.11.8 as a dependency to your app. What if you try to use Scala 2.10.x instead?

Comment: @AntonOkolnychyi You are 100% correct, please write an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to include Scala 2.11.8 as a dependency in your application, while Spark artifacts rely on Scala 2.10.

You have two options to solve your problem:

- Use Scala 2.10.x
- Use Spark artifacts that rely on Scala 2.11 (e.g. spark-core_2.11 instead of spark-core_2.10)

Comment: Spark, starting from 2.0, uses Scala 2.11 as default Scala version. I highly recommend upgrading Spark version

Comment: @T.Gawęda yep, I completely agree.

Comment: Thank you Sir! i used 2.10.x version ! and i changed the container of the scala library.